# Are circulant matrices open

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices

Are the set of positive definite symmetric circulant matrices open in the set of positive definite symmetric matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n \geq 3$, the answer is no.  Define the matrix 
$$
M = 
\pmatrix{
1 & 1 &&& 0\\
1 & 1 &&& \\
&&    0 &&\\
&&& \ddots & \\
0&&&&0
}
$$

Note that for all positive definite, symmetric, circulant matrices $A$ and for all $\epsilon > 0$, $A + \epsilon M$ is a positive definite symmetric matrix that is non-circulant.

Or, if you prefer, note that the set of symmetric circulant matrices is closed in the set of size $n$ positive definite matrices, and that the set of size $n$ PD matrices has no non-trivial clopen subsets.

Comment: The second part of your statement does not make sense to me. How can symmetric circulant matrices be closed in positive definite symmetric matrices when there exists singular symmetric circulant matrices?

Comment: @mtiano I meant the set of positive definite symmetric circulant matrices

Comment: That's what I thought you meant, but can you explain why the set is closed?

Comment: @mtiano the way I think of it as follows: any proper vector subspace of a finite dimensional vector space is closed in that vector space, so the set of all circulant matrices is closed.  Let $S$ be the set of symmetric PD matrices, let $C$ be the set of circulant matrices.  Since $C$ is closed in $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$, $S \cap C$ is closed in $S$.  $S$ is connected because it is convex.